# Android: Issue while saving Hasmap in parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am facing an issue while saving a HashMap on Parse and then retrieving it.
Below is the code to put data in the ParseObject.

```
HashMap<Object, Object> eventInfo = new HashMap<>();
eventInfo.put(ParseTable.Column.AllDay, allday);
JSONArray dateSet = new JSONArray();
JSONObject sdObj = new JSONObject();
sdObj.put("__type", "String");
sdObj.put("iso", sdf.format(sdate));
JSONObject edObj = new JSONObject();
edObj.put("__type", "String");
edObj.put("iso", sdf.format(rEnd.getTime()));
dateSet.put(sdObj);
dateSet.put(edObj);

eventInfo.put(ParseTable.Column.DateSet, dateSet);
eventInfo.put(ParseTable.Column.EventType, eType.getText().toString());
eventInfo.put(ParseTable.Column.Location, loc.getText().toString());
eventInfo.put(ParseTable.Column.Points, points.getText().toString());
obj.put(ParseTable.Column.EventInfo, eventInfo);
```

Now when I get this data from the same object in which I have set it, its correct.

```
{eventType=Default, location=, allDay=false, dateSet=[{"__type":"String","iso":"2015-02-25T21:18:00Z"},{"__type":"String","iso":"2015-02-28T00:00:00Z"}], points=}
```

This also saves properly on server:

```
{"allDay":false,"dateSet":[{"__type":"String","iso":"2015-02-25T21:18:00Z"},{"__type":"String","iso":"2015-02-28T00:00:00Z"}],"eventType":"Default","location":"","points":""}
```

But when I retrieve the same data from Parse server, this is what it returns, when I log the HashMap:

```
{eventType=Default, location=, allDay=false, dateSet=[null, null], points=}
```

Don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Please show us how you are retrieving the data from parse.

Comment: Map<String, Object> oinfo = event.getMap(ParseTable.Column.EventInfo);

Comment: I added an answer with what I think might be happening but it would be easier to help if I could see where your `event` object comes from in the line you just posted in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting a blank field is because you are calling `getMap` on a blank/empty `event` object.

`Map<String, Object> oinfo = event.getMap(ParseTable.Column.EventInfo);`

I can't see where your `event` object comes from but I also don't see that you have saved any of this data to the database.

So make sure that `obj` has been saved:

`obj.saveInBackground()`

Then you can get your `eventInfo` out after making a query:

```
ParseQuery q = ParseQuery.getQuery("YourClass");
        q.whereEqualTo("someColumnName", "someValue");
        q.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(List objects, ParseException paramParseException) {
                for (Object o: objects){
                    Map<String, Object> oinfo = o.getMap(ParseTable.Column.EventInfo);
                }
            }
        });
```

If you are actually saving the `obj` already to the database and only attempting to grab data from a populated `event` object then please update your question with each step you are taking to get the data from the server.  I would like to see the entire lifecycle of the `event` object.

Comment: It is getting saved properly on server, see I mentioned "This also saves properly on server...", so the json I mentioned afterwards is what getting saved on server.

Comment: Yes I can see that but I still have no idea where `event` comes from in your line of code `Map<String, Object> oinfo = event.getMap(ParseTable.Column.EventInfo); `.  I need to know how `event` was created/instantiated before you try to call `.getMap()`

Comment: I am fetching this from server, using ParseQuery and saving it as a Map.

Comment: Please post your query in your question